# jQueryMobile page transition not loading page as it should

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-transitions

I am trying to load a page with transition effect on click of a link. I have used **jQuery Mobile**.
Below is my code.

```
<a href="index.html" data-transition="slide">Transition</a>
```

On click of **Transition** link **index.html** page should be loaded showing transition effect.

Below is the output of **index.html** that I am trying to load.

[image]

But problem is that when I click **Transition** link the index page is not loaded as expected. The loaded page looks like below.

[image]

When I looked through firebug what is happening, I found that instead of loading complete page what transition is doing that it is putting output of linked page( i.e index.html) into first page and applying css of first page to it.

I want transition to load index page properly with its all css not to embed it into the page link is called from.

Can you please tell me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

In JQM by default when you link to another page JQM looks for the first JQM page ([without](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) any of the scripts or styles on that page)on that page (`data-role="page"`) and then via *ajax* pulls it and *enhances* it and attaches it to the DOM of the current page. If you want to *fully load* the second page instead then you need to either set `ajax-enabled` to `false` (this is a global setting) or on the link to the second page add the attribute [data-rel="extrenal"](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html).

Comment: but does page transitions are supported if `data-rel` is used?

Comment: [No](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-links.html), page transitions are only supported when the page is fetched through *ajax* (this is because both pages need to be in the DOM to kick off the transition).

Comment: is there a way I can retain CSS of second page while using transitions?

Comment: Have you tried Native Elements? data-enhance="false"  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html this might be what you're looking for

Comment: @Sandy As @PhillPafford just mentioned you can use the `data-enhance="false"` attribute which tells JQM not to *enhance* the elements in that container.  You can then style that page as you wish

Answer (score 0):

Add in your html link tag the following attribute:  rel="external"

```
<a href="index.html" data-transition="slide" rel="external">Transition</a>
```