# jquery plugin for page transition

Tags: jquery-plugins, css-transitions

I am writing a simple HTML5 application for iPad and I am looking for a simple jquery solution for page transition. I know you would recommend **jQueryMobile** but problem with that it uses ajax to loads next page in current page and then kicks off transition so css of the page that I m trying to load is getting disturbed [**see my question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408506/jquerymobile-page-transition-not-loading-page-as-it-should/12408967#comment16680961_12408967).  I also tried **[this](http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/)** and this plugin was the thing that I was looking for but problem with this is that it is not working with iPad and also page flickers a lot while transition so I dropped this option. Another option I found is jQTouch but as far as I know jQTouch only works for transition effects to div, not sure how to use it for page transition.

What I want is that on click of **Transition** link in `<a href="index.html">Transition</a>` index.html should get displayed with transition effects without flickering and css disturbance of index.html page.

Could someone please recommend me some plugins using which I can achieve page transitions without disturbing CSS while transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this works for you... the below solution worked for me although jQuery is needed:

First right after the body tag add this:

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Then add the style class for the div and image to your css:

```
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

And finally add this javascript to your page (preferably at the end of your page, before closing body tag of course):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
$(window).load(function() {
$('#loading').hide();   }); 
</script>
```

Then adjust the position of the loading image and the background color of the loading div via the style class.

This is it, works just fine. But of course you have to have an ajax-loader.gif somewhere.

Try AJAXLoad They have some great animated GIF's there.. :)